# angular project running in port 4000 but cannot see in browser

Tags: angular, centos

I am trying to run an angular project in the server using centos. It is complied successfully but working in browse when I try with my ip and port number.

I have no idea with deploying in the server, i tried to research but couldn't find anything related to this.

I started the project with the below command

```
   ng serve --port 4000 --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck
```

I just need to view it in the browser just let me know if there is some solution like where i have to re-route it to correct port with some way or something

Comment: Is your network public, check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55197759/3937794)

Comment: Both solutions worked for me

`ng serve --public --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000` and 

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000 --disableHostCheck true`

Comment: @SouravDutta : Both the commands are not working.. I think the problem is with something else ..But am not getting the point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was working so i took the production build of the angular with the below code.
`ng build --prod` 
and pasted all the files inside the dist folder to the **public_html** folder on the server and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

let me give a brief note on your question.

As you said you are running an Angular project on `CentOS`. so, let me assume your CentOS IP address as (`192.168.0.100`).

and run Angular project with the following command

```
ng serve --host 192.168.0.100
```

and access the project through in your local network with `192.168.0.100:4200` in the browser.

Hope it will work for you !!

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it isn't working .. :( Is there something to do with .htaccess file in my cloud server